# WebSocket error using nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I'm getting error in client server connection using WebSocket nodejs
I'm using **node-websocket-server** https://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server
Error :
*WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing **

**Server code (server.js)**:

```
var ws = require(__dirname + '/lib/ws/server');

var server = ws.createServer();

server.addListener("connection", function (conn) {

console.log("A connection established with connection id "+ conn.id);

var msg = "Welcome " + conn.id + " joining the party." +
    "Total connection : " + server.manager.length;

server.broadcast(msg);

});

server.listen(8000);

console.log("Websocket server is running...");

console.log("Listening to port 8000");
```

**Client code** :

```
var websock = {};

$(function(){

    if(window["WebSocket"]){

    websock.socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000");

    websock.socket.onopen = function(e){
        console.log("WebSocket connection established");
    };

    websock.socket.onmessage = function(e){
        console.log(e.data);
    };

    websock.socket.onclose = function(e){
        console.log("WebSocket connection closed.");
    };

    }
   });
```

**index.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WebSockets</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/client.websocket.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I dont know what's the problem here.Thanks in advance.